# C# viewmodel : Mapping unnamed string array from JSON

Tags: c#, json, viewmodel

I'm trying to create a C# viewmodel to map the follwing JSON :

```
"choices": {
        "5": {
            "Id": 16,
            "Name": "Sterk",
            "FoodPropertyId": 5
        },
        "6": {
            "Id": 17,
            "Name": "Pommes Frites",
            "FoodPropertyId": 6
        }
    },
```

As you might notice.. "5" and "6" are just values, and are not valuable at all in my viewmodel. Problem is.. the array-data inside is what i need.

Can someone tell me how to map this into a viewmodel ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary for the `choices` .The key will be a numeric type and value will be the class representing each item with those 3 properties.

```
public class RootData
{        
    public Dictionary<int, FoodItem> Choices { set; get; }
}
public class FoodItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FoodPropertyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This should work for the below JSON

```
{
    "choices": {
        "5": {
            "Id": 16,
            "Name": "Sterk",
            "FoodPropertyId": 5
        },
        "6": {
            "Id": 17,
            "Name": "Pommes Frites",
            "FoodPropertyId": 6
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : As per the comment, adding the code to access this.

You can loop through the `Choices` dictionary and read each key and the value(a `FoodItem` object)

Here is a sample using the `RootData` class as the parameter of a wep api 2 controller action method.

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(RootData value)
{
    if (value != null && value.Choices != null)
    {
        foreach (var valueChoice in value.Choices)
        {
            int theNumber = valueChoice.Key;
            FoodItem foodItem = valueChoice.Value;

            var name = foodItem.Name;
            var id   = foodItem.Id;
        }
    }
    return Ok("All good");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shyju :) Can you also add how to actually loop through these items so i can access the Id, Name and FoodPropertyId ? 

foreach (var item in choicesdictionary) // how to access second-part of dictionary (FoodItem) ?

Comment: Probably the greatest, most understandable and quickest answer i've got on Stack Overflow in years!.. Thanks @Shyju :)